# Regex - Get all commas from text expression besides ones in functions

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem with regex expression. I want to find all commas "," in text expression but not ones in functions. The text expression is something like `2,5 + x + min(2,3,4)`

So:

`2,3 #finds comma`

`(2,3) #finds comma`

`min(2,3) #ignores`

The regex that I've tried to write only excludes brackets from my expression and looks like `/,(?![^(]*\))/g` but exclude only the function brackets like `min(2,4,5)`

Thanks!

Comment: How do we know if it's used in a function? What if it's in a string?

Comment: function is recognized by some letters and "(" just after it. I can ignore commas in strings because only param names are allowed

Comment: What is the tool or language? Can you have nested functions?

Comment: I'm using C# so I think so

Comment: Then maybe `(?<!\w\([^()]*),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\w\([^()]*),
```

*Details*:

- `(?<!\w\([^()]*)` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with a word char, `(` and then zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`.
- `,` - a comma.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UtwwAH/1).

Comment: I've found an edgecase, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MHgsde/3)

Comment: @UlanyPan What are you doing with the found commas? Replacing/extracting/splitting?

Comment: I am replacing them with dots.

Comment: @UlanyPan Then use `Regex.Replace(text, @"\w\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*\)|(?<c>,)", m => m.Groups["c"].Success ? "." : m.Value)`